# Word for excessive use of adjectives or a long stream of adjectives

Tags: single-word-requests

I was tasked with analyzing an article, and I encountered within the text a long sentence with a stream of adjectives, e.g.

> Gove and all the other know-nothing know-it-alls happily continue to peddle their **sneering, condescending, dismissive, misanthropic, elitist, made-up twaddle**.

Is there an appellation for such an occurrence? In addition, is there a specific word for excessive use of adjectives? I know circumlocution may be appropriate for the second question, but I was hoping there was a word specific to adjectives or adverbs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[**Synathroesmus**](http://grammar.about.com/od/rs/g/synathroesterm.htm): A rhetorical term for the piling up of words (usually adjectives), often in the spirit of invective.